# Deleting Kth element in Circular queue

Tags: queue

In a circular queue represented by an array, how can one specify the number of elements in the queue in terms of “front”, “rear” and MAX-QUEUE-SIZE? Write a “C” function to delete the K-th element from the “front” of a circular queue.

What does delete the K-th element mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of elements in the queue will be
`(rear - front) % MAX_QUEUE_SIZE`

`Rear-Front` will give us the difference between their pointer locations, which will help us know the number of elements between them. Now since this is a circular queue, the rear can be smaller than the front too, so we need to find the Modulus by the size of the queue.

Will update the post with solutions to the other two too!